# Javascript Angular Google Map Autocomplete Api not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps

I'm trying to se the google map api in angular with the following code:
HTML:

```
<div ng-value="initMap()"> 
          <div>
          <input id="pac-input" type="text"
                  value="{{event_foundaddress}}"  ng-model="event_foundaddress"/> <!-- placeholder breaks EVERYTHING!!!! No placeholder!!!-->
          </div>

          <div  id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 400px" > </div>

          <div > Found address: {{event_foundaddress}} </div>
       </div>
```

JS/angular

```
$scope.initMap = function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: $scope.lat, lng: $scope.long},//london coords
    zoom: 13
  });
  $scope.foundaddress = $localStorage.event.address
  var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
      (document.getElementById('pac-input'));
     //$scope.event_foundaddress
  //alert('in:'+input)
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  //var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
  //map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);
  //alert(input)
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,{types: ['geocode']});
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);


  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });


  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {...


  }
```

I got an error InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement from the var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,{types: ['geocode']});. Apparently input is not a HTMLInputElement. Do you know how to pass through a HTMLInputElement from the dom in angular?

EDIT:
putting an alert('input') reveals that the input variable is always null... not sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, you have to call `initMap()` on `ng-focus` of input element. Then it will work.

But the problem even after updating my code, the model wasnt updated. Then I moved to angular-google-places-autocomplete library.

And that library is awesome. Check out https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete

Edit: Answer Updated
You just have to write as below, and once you select the location `foundaddress` will have Google place object, from which you have to extract formatted_address.

```
<input ng-model="foundaddress" type="text" id="pac-input" g-places-autocomplete></input>
```

Comment: If I put <input id="pac-input" type="text" ng-focus="initMap()" value="{{event_foundaddress}}"  ng-model="event_foundaddress"/>. The code doesn't even load the map

Comment: Use this, var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('pac-input') you dint pass the correct id

Comment: I don't think the name is the problem: 'map' id is the place where the map is displayed, 'pac-input' is where the autocomplete should perform

Comment: I tried also the angular-google-places-autocomplete library but still same error at var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,{types: ['geocode']});

Comment: I've updated my answer check it out. You dont need to use initMap() if you use angular-google-places-autocomplete library

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. When I type on the autocomplete the foundaddress is not an object but simply the string I typed.

Comment: Any errors in the console log ? Did you include key given by google places API ?

Comment: I think I solved I had to set the apikey on the google map api instead. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. Happy coding